# Javascript (TCP) socket API that does not require an additional server

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets

I'm aware that several Javascript/browser socket APIs e.g. websockets, socket.io etc are now availble. But as far as I know all these APIs/technologies require an additional server process e.g. a websockets or sockets.io sever in addition to an HTTP server. It matters because (I assume that) most webhosts do not provide such servers out of the box, wheras I am looking to avoid expensive hosting options -- if possible.

Is there such a socket API? I am willing to limit myself to a browser provided it has a native socket API.

PS: hosting a server in my bedroom is not an option for security reasons.

Comment: There are inexpensive VPS solutions (I've seen $5/mo providers) on which you could run your own setup. If you might fancy Node.js, `socket.io` works well in combination with Express in one process.

Comment: I'm sorry but what's VPS and Express? I've googled but they are are fairly common terms. (I'm a web dev newbie -- I primarily program in C++).

Comment: VPS is a Virtual Private Server, like webhosting but you get your own actual (though virtual) server at your disposal so you can install/run anything you like. [Express](http://expressjs.com/) is one of the most common frameworks for Node to implement HTTP servers.